# How to insert date into datetime column in SQL Server using ado.net programming with transactions in mvc

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Not able to insert date into datetime column in sql server. 
While debugging after the first executeNonQuery() statement debugger jumps to catch block 
and it's displaying the following message in sqlError parameter in catch block:
'Incorrect Syntax near 12'

```
public ActionResult AddStudentData(StudentDetails sd)
{
    SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\StudentDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");

    SqlTransaction transaction;

    db.Open();
    transaction = db.BeginTransaction();

    SqlCommand cmd = db.CreateCommand();

    try
    {
        **cmd.CommandText = "insert into StudentDetails(StudentName, DOB, Description, Gender) values ('" + sd.StudentName + "'," +sd.DOB + ",'" + sd.Description + "','" + sd.Gender + "')";

        cmd.Transaction = transaction;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();**

        cmd.CommandText = "select max(StudentID) from StudentDetails";
        int id = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        cmd.CommandText = "insert into Qualification (StudentID, Qualification, POY) values ("+id+",'"+sd.Qualification+"',"+sd.POY+")";
        cmd.Transaction = transaction;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (SqlException sqlError)
    {
        string s = sqlError.Message.ToString();
        transaction.Rollback();
    }

    db.Close();
    return View("SuccessAddStudentData");
}
```

Thank You
Dilipkumar

Comment: Please text your full error message and also mention at which line you are getting error?

Comment: Use parameterised queries. Not only do they make your code safer, but they avoid having to pass in values by concatenation which can lead to errors.

Answer (score 0):

Note that date values (DOB) must also contain single quotes.

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into StudentDetails(StudentName, DOB, Description, Gender) 
values ('" + sd.StudentName + "','" +sd.DOB + "','" + 
sd.Description + "','" + sd.Gender + "')";
```

Also, keep in mind the date format based on SQL Server.
And lastly as other posts mentioned, use bind parameters to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: I have resolved the issue .But i have doubt regarding passing the values in query " we pass values  with single quotes for varchar type in sql server ". is it applicable for datetime values too?? if YES then if i hard code values in query without single quotes it's inserting please let me know why??

Comment: You should follow Tomas Lielacher's post to make use of bind parameters. But if you build dynamic SQL as per your original post, it is best to use single quotes for dates. For the problem rises if your date format is something like YYYY/MM/DD. This will be seen as performing division between the numbers resulting in a weird or invalid date...

Answer (score 0):

You should ALWAYS use parameterized queries when accessing a SQL database, otherwise your application might be vulnerable to SQL injection. You also should use `using` when dealing with objects for database access. For example, when the using block is left, the connection will be closed no matter if an exception was thrown or not.

```
        try
        {
            using (var db = new SqlConnection("connection string"))
            using (var transaction = db.BeginTransaction())
            using (var cmd = db.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.Transaction = transaction;
                db.Open();

                cmd.CommandText = "insert into StudentDetails(StudentName, DOB, Description, Gender) values(@name, @dob, @desc, @gender)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", sd.StudentName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", sd.DOB);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", sd.Description);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", sd.Gender);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();

                // other queries

                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            string s = ex.Message.ToString();
        }
```